# Angular 6 how to set navbar menu active when user scroll to div id

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

How I can get the div id when I scroll to the div.

My angular 6 app is one page app which when user click to the nav bar the page will slide to the div id (I use ngx-scroll-to).

I have done when user click the navbar menu it will slide to the div and set the class active.

My problem is when user manually scroll, how I can set navbar menu active when it reach the div id.

```
          <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='home' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link " (click)="active('home')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#home'">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='services' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link" (click)="active('services')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#services'">Services</a>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of @HostListner. from angular.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    scrollHandler(event) {
      console.debug("Scroll Event");
    }
```

and in template

```
<div  (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)"  >
       <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='home' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link " (click)="active('home')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#home'">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='services' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link" (click)="active('services')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#services'">Services</a>
          </li>
....
    </div>
```

> please note the above HostListener will call a function on window
>   scroll as we mentioned ('window:scroll') if you want to call this
>   function on div scroll just add ('scroll') to HostListener