# How to make the link active change when scrolling?

Tags: angular

I use [ngx-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll#readme). How to make the link active change when scrolling?

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-items">
    <li><a pageScroll href="#default" class="active">Default</a></li>
    <li><a pageScroll href="#first">First</a></li>
    <li><a pageScroll href="#second">Second</a></li>
    <li><a pageScroll href="#third">Third</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="blocks">
  <div class="block" id="first">First</div>
  <div class="block" id="second">Second</div>
  <div class="block" id="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Github of this library](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll/wiki/FAQ#is-it-possible-to-detect-the-current-scroll-section) i found that

> Detecting the current scroll section is not possible with ngx-page-scroll. This library only manipulates the scroll position but does not perform any "read" actions of the current scroll position. Look for something like "scrollspy", for example by using the ngx-scrollspy project.
> Blockquote

So you will need to code this feature without the help of this library.
you can easily do so :

You can use the power of @HostListner. from angular.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) 
    scrollHandler(event) {
      console.debug("Scroll Event");
    }
```

and in template

```
<div  (scroll)="scrollHandler($event)"  >
       <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='home' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link " (click)="active('home')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#home'">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="activeRoute=='services' ? 'active' : ''">
              <a class="nav-link" (click)="active('services')" onclick="return false;" href="#" [ngx-scroll-to]="'#services'">Services</a>
          </li>
....
    </div>
```

please note the above HostListener will call a function on window scroll as we mentioned ('window:scroll') if you want to call this function on div scroll just add ('scroll') to HostListener

source: [Angular 6 how to set navbar menu active when user scroll to div id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619140/angular-6-how-to-set-navbar-menu-active-when-user-scroll-to-div-id)